# Keycloak Spring Boot adapter and anonymous resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I cannot get Keycloak to skip authorization checks for a path with public resources.

We are using the Spring Boot Keycloak Adapter.

We have tried the following solutions:

1. Did not specify path using security constraints in app properties (no mapping for "/static/*")
2. Use "public" for the following

   ```
       keycloak.security-constraints[10].securityCollections[0].name=public
       keycloak.security-constraints[10].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/static/*
   ```
3. In SecurityConfig.configure()

   ```
   http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
   ```

Read about using a policy enforcer, but there are no instructions on doing this with Spring Boot other than using a policy-enforcer-config. I have no idea where to specify since we don't have a keycloak.json file.

Everything above always results in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.facade.SimpleHttpFacade.getSecurityContext(SimpleHttpFacade.java:63) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.corsRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:102) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AuthenticatedActionsHandler.handledRequest(AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:54) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:78) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at com.testing.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:79) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:82) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.43.jar:8.0.43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Teo It's not working properly for me either. They have this ticket closed on their JIRA but I'm still getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken
`

Comment: @doublemc and so? what can we do?

Comment: @Teo haven't found anything that works properly - thought you might have on your own ;)

Comment: @doublemc it seem like we are not alone :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228797/unauthorized-request-401-using-spring-if-i-open-a-modal-or-i-send-an-ajax-requ

Answer (score 5):

Other posts mentioned calling web.ignoring()..., but I was overriding the configure(HttpSecurity) method which doesn't have the ignoring method.

I finally realized that I can override both configure methods (HttpSecurity and WebSecurity) to accomplish this.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/*");
}
```

It would be nice if we could specify anonymous access using keycloak parameters in the application properties file, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be resolved by adding below code as its provided into https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6468

```
@Override
public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/keycloak.json"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar desired configuration in my application and was running into the same exception. I was able to get around it by overriding a few of Keycloak's classes and adding an `isAssignableFrom(Class)` check in HTTP facade's `getSecurityContext()` method:

```
/**
 * Hack to fix issue accessing resources anonymously while Keycloak adapter is part of the security chain.
 */
public class FixedKeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter extends KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FixedKeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.class);

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private AdapterDeploymentContext deploymentContext;

    FixedKeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter() {
        super();
    }

    /*
     * Must override this because deploymentContext is set to private on the super class
     */
    @Override
    protected void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {
        super.initFilterBean();

        deploymentContext = applicationContext.getBean(AdapterDeploymentContext.class);
    }

    /*
     * Must override this because applicationContext is set to private on the super class
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        // use our fixed facade class
        HttpFacade facade = new FixedSimpleHttpFacade((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
        AuthenticatedActionsHandler handler = new AuthenticatedActionsHandler(deploymentContext.resolveDeployment(facade), (OIDCHttpFacade)facade);
        boolean handled = handler.handledRequest();
        if (handled) {
            log.debug("Authenticated filter handled request: {}", ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI());
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hack to add missing class check on {@link SimpleHttpFacade#getSecurityContext()}.
     */
    static class FixedSimpleHttpFacade extends SimpleHttpFacade {
        /**
         * Creates a new simple HTTP facade for the given request and response.
         *
         * @param request  the current <code>HttpServletRequest</code> (required)
         * @param response the current <code>HttpServletResponse</code> (required)
         */
        FixedSimpleHttpFacade(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(request, response);
        }

        @Override
        public KeycloakSecurityContext getSecurityContext() {
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

            if (context != null && context.getAuthentication() != null &&
                    // this check is missing in the super class
                    KeycloakAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getAuthentication().getClass())
                ) {
                KeycloakAuthenticationToken authentication = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) context.getAuthentication();
                return authentication.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I override the method that returns that particular filter in my `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass:

```
/**
 * Override to return our fixed filter.
 * @return An instance of our fixed {@link KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter}.
 */
@Bean
@Override
protected KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter() {
    return new FixedKeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter();
}
```

Now I am able to hit my public endpoints with no auth and my secured endpoints still work as expected.

This seems like a simple check...I am not sure why it is not included in the `SimpleHttpFacade` that ships with the Keycloak Spring Security adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using keycloak-spring-boot adapter, you just need to avoid declare a Role for that security constraint, for example:

```
    keycloak:
      realm: Demo
      auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
      ssl-required: none
      resource: demo-service
      credentials:
        secret: your-service-credentials
      bearer-only: true
      principal-attribute: preferred_username
      use-resource-role-mappings: true
      security-constraints:
        -
          authRoles:

          securityCollections:
            -
              name: public
              patterns:
                - /actuator/health
        -
          authRoles:
            - SECURE_ROLE
          securityCollections:
            -
              name: protected
              patterns:
                - /secure/*
```

In YAML file above, I declare the URL /actuator/health as public, as you can see, it doesn't have a Role. 
The user needs a SECURE_ROLE to get access to all links under /secure/ URL.