# Unauthorized request, 401, using Spring if I open a modal or I send an ajax request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, http-status-code-401

I have a problem with **Keycloak** and **Spring Boot**..

I developed a web-app with some modal and ajax request, sometimes, and I don't know why, I receive `status 401` if I click on an href to open a modal, or if I submit a form via ajax...

I don't see any error log server-side,  but I checked the request and I have `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="Unknown"`. I think it is weird.

This is the entire request:

```
1.       Request URL:
    MyUrl
2.       Request Method:
    GET
3.       Status Code:
    401 Unauthorized
4.       Remote Address:
    MyIp
5.       Referrer Policy:
    no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
1.       Cache-Control:
    no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
2.       Connection:
    Keep-Alive
3.       Content-Language:
    it
4.       Content-Length:
    302
5.       Content-Type:
    text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
6.       Date:
    Tue, 08 May 2018 07:32:59 GMT
7.       Expires:
    0
8.       Keep-Alive:
    timeout=5, max=99
9.       Pragma:
    no-cache
10.    Server:
    Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
11.    WWW-Authenticate:
    Bearer realm="Unknown"
12.    X-Content-Type-Options:
    nosniff
13.    X-Frame-Options:
    DENY
14.    X-XSS-Protection:
    1; mode=block

Request Header
1.       Accept:
    text/html, */*; q=0.01
2.       Accept-Encoding:
    gzip, deflate
3.       Accept-Language:
    it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
4.       Connection:
    keep-alive
5.       Cookie:
    JSESSIONID=1F97669EEE8A347CAE145C8D25146512.Tomcat1; _ga=GA1.2.230482432.1486023475
6.       DNT:
    1
7.       Host:
    MyHost
8.       Referer:
    MyUrl
9.       User-Agent:
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
10.    X-Requested-With:
    XMLHttpRequest

Query String Parameters
.....
```

This is my config about keycloak and Spring:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Autowired
    public KeycloakClientRequestFactory keycloakClientRequestFactory;

    public SecurityConfig() {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http
            .httpBasic()
            .disable();

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority("1086")
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl(URL)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate() {
        return new KeycloakRestTemplate(keycloakClientRequestFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean( KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
           .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**");
    }
```

I can continue with the request, if I reload the page, and then I re-click on the href... But why I have to reload the page? and why sometimes?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue using the ruby client. "why sometimes?"